# UNION with a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is what I am trying to do

```
EXEC sp1 1

SELECT * FROM x 
UNION
if(@num <= 1)
EXEC sp1(2)
else
null //want to return null to stop
```

I could do this is with a programming language but I don't have an idea what is that I am doing wrong with programming in SQL?

Comment: I vote for passing `@num` to the stored procedure.

Comment: `IF` is a logical flow operator; you can't put it in the middle of a `SELECT` statement. Nor can you `EXEC` in a `SELECT`. Simply put, the above is completely invalid. *"I could do this is with a programming language"* SQL *isn't* a programming language; don't treat it like one as it is nothing like one.

Comment: so I cant even do `Union` with a sp? 
Something like Select * from (Exec sp1()) ?

@Larnu

Comment: You can `exec` into a temp table... and then use the temp table. I recommend checking out some SQL tutorials though, you need to get familiar with the basics before you start attempting this level of complexity.

Comment: *"so I cant even do Union with a sp?"* No. You don't "`SELECT`" from a stored procedure, you execute it.

Comment: @Larnu yeah so Union All Exec sp1() will work?

Comment: No, @Shad ... `UNION ALL` doesn't start a query. A `UNION ALL` needs to be preceded with (and followed by) a `SELECT` statement. I really suggest reading the documentation on these operators work; it's very complete and informative, and would show you why what you have isn't valid. Again, SQL is *not* a programming language. It isn't written like one, it isn't parsed like one, and it doesn't run like one; don't treat it like a programming language because it isn't. You can't "lump" an operator in front of another and expect it to work.

Comment: Note, you *could* use something like `OPENROWSET` or `OPENQUERY` to run the `EXEC` in a deferred statement, but I really don't suggest that; especially with the apparent lack of fundamental knowledge you have of T-SQL. You're far better off thinking about what you really want to achieve here and using a different approach. Likely you'll be better off creating an **inline** table-value function.

Comment: I just have no idea what is going on.  What is `@num`?  How is `x` being populated?  Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This, honestly, makes no sense, and I still suggest that you use an **inline** Table-value function here, instead of a procedure, but you *can* do something like this using `OPENROWSET` to return the dataset from a stored procedure within a `SELECT` statement. It *can't* be parametrised though (not in the traditional sense), and if you don't understand this, don't use it.

This is pseudo SQL as well as there's a lack of enough information to provide a complete solution, such as the columns needed in the `SELECT`s, but it *might* get you there if you can comprehend it:

```sql
EXEC dbo.sp1 1;

SELECT {Columns}
FROM dbo.x
UNION ALL
SELECT {Same Columns again} --This dataset's definition must be IDENTICAL to the above against your table dbo.x
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Database={YourDatabase}','EXEC dbo.sp1(2);') ORS; --Assumes you are using Windows Authentication
WHERE @Num <= 1
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL,NULL,NULL{,NULL...} --Until you have you enough NULL columns
```

Note that in this example I am using the deprecated SQLNCLI connection manager. You should really be using [MSOLEDBSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/connect/oledb/download-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15), however, the only instance I currently have access to with a trusted connection is a 2012 instance which doesn't have that driver installed; so I didn't want to post code that I hadn't minimally tested.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in SQL this way:

```
SELECT * into #temp FROM x

if(@num <= 1)
begin
    insert into #temp
    EXEC sp1(2)

    select * from #temp
end
else
begin
    select  null
end
```

First you create a temp table and insert x table records into it and after that you check your condition and then insert records from procedure and then `select * from #temp` and other case it will return null.